# opencover ui code coverage results not showing coverage for my tests, but for other .dlls

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, opencover

As I am using VS 2015 professional, and code coverage is not available for me.
I was following this guide:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6950a046-8919-4935-8542-c6f37956f688
Everything is fine except **Step 3.** It doesn't show my classes and methods, but some other .dlls.
Screenshot:
[image]
Any suggestions why it is not showing code coverage for my methods?
Thanks

Comment: Are you producing PDBs for your assemblies and are they in the same folder as your assemblies during test execution?

Comment: yes, should the .pdb files be removed from projects?

Comment: OpenCover needs the PDBs to determine the injection points and determine which lines are covered by each point.